# Task does not execute in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a task on snowflake using CREATE TASK command.
However, the task seems to be suspended, so I wanted to resume the task by following commend:

```
ALTER TASK TASK_DELETE3 RESUME;
```

I'm receiving following error message:
Cannot execute task , EXECUTE TASK privilege must be granted to owner role

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: The error message is your solution.  You need to have EXECUTE TASK privilege added to the role that created the TASK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to run this command as ACCOUNTADMIN

`GRANT EXECUTE TASK ON ACCOUNT TO ROLE <your_role>`

Comment: Thank you, @demircioglu.

Comment: Anyone know how to execute this in Terraform?

Comment: To answer my own question: it's the snowflake_account_grant resource